# Route controller resolve mixed up

Tags: angularjs

I've a problem with 2 resolves, one for each controller.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvivera/RhAHy/

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', [], function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: 'Home {{model}}',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        resolve: HomeCtrl.resolve
    })
    .when('/About', {
        template: 'About {{model}}',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        resolve: AboutCtrl.resolve
    });
});

var HomeCtrl = app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, HomeCtrlData){
    $scope.model = HomeCtrlData;
});

HomeCtrl.resolve = {
    HomeCtrlData: function($q, $timeout){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function(){
            return deferred.resolve('AboutCtrlResolver');
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};

var AboutCtrl = app.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope, AboutCtrlData){
    $scope.model = AboutCtrlData;
});

AboutCtrl.resolve = {
    AboutCtrlData: function($q, $timeout){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function(){
            return deferred.resolve('AboutCtrlResolver');
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

In the jsfiddler script, when the HomeCtrl want to resolve HomeCtrlData I receive this error Unknown provider: HomeCtrlDataProvider <- HomeCtrlData

If I change HomeCtrlData to AboutCtrlData in the HomeCtrl everything works, it seems that the only resolve that is assigned is AboutCtrl.resolve

Any idea?

Comment: If you inline what HomeCtrl.resolve is set to -- i.e., `resolve: { HomeCtrlData: ...}` it works, but I don't know why.  (Also, I think the first place `AboutCtrlResolver` appears in your code should instead be `HomeCtrlResolver`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `app.controller()` doesn't return the controller, it returns your application module. So you're assigning `app.resolve` twice, which is why it doesn't work for one of them.

I would suggest that you inline the resolve function like this instead:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', [], function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: 'Home {{model}}',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        resolve: {
            HomeCtrlData: function($q, $timeout) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function(){
                    return deferred.resolve('HomeCtrlData');
                }, 2000);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/About', {
        template: 'About {{model}}',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        resolve: {
            AboutCtrlData: function($q, $timeout) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function(){
                    return deferred.resolve('AboutCtrlData');
                }, 2000);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
});
```